# How can I take user input and search it in python?

Tags: python, string, input

I'm trying to create a basic personal assistant that will listen to the user,and search things up,compute math, us wikipedia,youtube, and tell random quotes/jokes. For the first step of my project I want to make the program take the users input and search it up. When I was trying to do this, I couldn't get any of the search modules like selenium,or search_google to do what I needed,so i decided to use the python webbrowser module.I'm first testing it by having it take typed input by the user and search it up,but I'm having a problem with that.I have

```
asker = input("what do you want to search  ")
print (asker)
webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=(asker)")
```

However, it will only search the word asker,instead of the user input. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

`webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=({})".format(asker))`

This should help.

`asker` is the variable so you cannot put it with string statement like you did above.

Comment: Python 3.6+ f-strings `webbrowser.open(f"https://www.google.com/search?q=({asker})")`